# Using Results of CLR StoredProcedure in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, clr, sqlclr

I wrote a CLR-Stored Procedure, which queries a Webservice that returns a Dataset with three Tables.
When debugging in VS2010 or calling from SQL-ManagementStudio (exec CLR_stp param1,param2) I can see the correct tables returned...

But now I want a SPECIFIC Field from one of the Tables, for use in a standard T-SQL STP.

In pseudocode, I would do something like:

INSERT INTO AnyTable (Field)
SELECT Table1.FieldN FROM exec CLR_stp(param1, param2)....

Obviously this is nonsense, but you get what I mean.

So, how can I use the dataset returned from a CLR-STP in a T-SQL-STP ?

Thank you,
Reinhard

Answer (score 0):

If you define a temporary table that matches the output columns of the CLR procedure, you can:

```
insert #YourTable
exec dbo.YourSp @par1, @par2
```

You can run this in a normal stored procedure to access the first result.  It's not currently possible to access the 2nd or further recordset in a stored procedure.